# verbosity of yield syntax

Tags: c#, yield

I have interesting question. According to MSDN yield [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
yield return <expression>; // yield some value
yield break;               // exiting from iterator
```

Why not just:

```
yield <expression>;        // yield some value
return;                    // exiting from iterator
```

To me second form would be less verbose and still would have same meaning as first.
So the question is - Why first form was chosen by .NET designers ? What reasons may caused this ? What potential design problems second form has ?

Comment: Less verbose: yes, but is it also more clear?

Comment: What's not clear in this ? `return` part ? Throwing new keywords into language not always results in clearer ways ...

Comment: How will you differentiate between normal return; and return; iterator??

Comment: Simply - if method implements `IEnumerable` - `return` functions as `yield break`, otherwise - as good old `return` ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility: it would create a technical ambiguity (remember that `yield` is a *contextual* keyword, not a *reserved* keyword)... Unlikely, but:

```
struct yield {}
```

Then

```
yield x;
```

Is actually a variable declaration. With the "yield return x;", that is only valid one way.

No idea if this is true. Just a thought.

Comment: +1. Nice point. To me _contextual keywords_ smells like .NET should be re-engineered in a way without contextual keyword - replacing them with normal reserved keywords. So seems this is some kind of design hack for backwards compatibility :-)

Comment: @0x69 well, "design hack" may be another name for "adding language features"

Answer (score 5):

The main reason that yield by itself wasn't used was that it would introduce a new keyword, and might break backwards compatibility when dealing with old pieces of code.

Because of this, the C# language team decided to make yield a contextual keyword (it's only a keyword when followed by `return` or `break`).

Consider the following code:

```
yield variable;
```

yield could be the name of a `class` or a `struct` and this statement cold be a variable declaration.

And with a complex language like C# that is designed to be easy to write and maintain, you want statements to have only one meaning. If `return` did different things depending on whether you were in an iterator or not, you could have a serious limitation in the language.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2006/03/08/546296.aspx

Comment: +1 strikes me that this should be the accepted answer, given its inclusion of the authoritative source vs accepted answer being a (very educated) guess.

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement has the single meaning that it must return an expression of a method's return type.  Since iterators do not have `void` return types, exiting an iterator using the `return` statement does not adhere to this meaning since you are not "returning" anything.

`yield break` indicates that an iterator should exit without returning any more elements.  IMHO this makes the `yield break` statement clearer than using the `return` statement for this purpose.

Comment: Huh, `yield break` also does not returns anything...

Comment: My point exactly. `return` should always return something, `yield break` does not.

Comment: you miss `void` functions which does not return anything also.

Comment: @0x60 I understand your point.  In a `void` function this makes sense since the function literally does not return a value.  In an iterator, however, this is not the case.  I have updated my answer to account for this.

Comment: The interesting part in iterator that you don't see code which exactly returns iterator object - something like `return Enumerator`. We infer that it returns enumerator object only from function definition - which is self-contradicting design.